# Apps Script. Copy paste special values if criteria is met

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to apps script, and i find it difficult to build a script for work, so your help will be greatly appreciated.

What I need is a script that will copy cell only if criteria is met in column "M", then paste special values over the same cell to eliminate formulas.

EX: If in M3 i have "success", then the script to copy M3 and paste it with special value over the same cell M3.
Then to check the next cell in M column ( M2:M400) for "success" criteria.

Also, i need the script to be triggered by change in column "M". If there is a change in a cell in "M" column, then the script to run.
Can this be done?

[Sample sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cp_ELAlmPfaWxQsbtmq9YdwQIRqdBGrMuj2JLwjbFOE/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

#### Do if M equals success

```
function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs.forEach(r => {
    if(r[12] == "Success") {
      //do you operation here
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I want that  if(r[12] == "Success") { then its automatically copy that cell value and paste it back as value on the same cell where it get the value}, also help me that if there is some change in M column then its run the script automatically

Comment: function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs.forEach(r => {
    if(r[12] == "Success") {
      //do you operation here
    }
  })
}

Comment: 'function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs.forEach(r => {
    if(r[12] == "Success") {
      //do you operation here
    }
  })
}'